# MSTest: Deployment Items are not copied to test folder

Tags: mstest

I have been reading many posts that describe my problem but I cannot find a solution. In my test project I have a folder called, "resources".

- I have added this folder to the deployment items configuration.
- I enabled deployment items
- I made sure the file is marked "always copy"

I added the DeploymentItem annotment at the class level. The file never makes it the Testing "out" folder.

Can someone tell me what I missed?

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem(@"resources\descriptor.xml")]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
         XDocument descriptor = XDocument.Load("descriptor.xml");  //The barfs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the resharper test runner was the problem. If I run my tests using the VS test runner all is well.